# i am unable to understand this sorting function, it is working fine and return random values

Tags: javascript, sorting

this sorting function using 0.5 before Math.random function when it return i am unable to understand about this value, how this value is here?

```
 array.sort(()=>{
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
    });
```

Comment: `Math.random()` returns a number between  `0-1`. So, `0.5 - Math.random()` returns +ve and -ve randomly. This is a really bad and inefficient way to shuffle an array. There are a lot of alternative here: [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954)

Comment: Refer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random